# How to synchronize the speed of spawned object and spawning time interval?

Tags: unity, c#, spawning

I want a stream of enemies coming from the top of the screen one behind other in a line, with their speed (speed of the whole stream i.e. every enemy) increased over time.

When I simply increased their speed, a continuous stream of balls (which will be my enemies) is lost since objects are spawned at a fixed time interval irrespective of the varying speeds of the spawned balls.

To maintain the continuous flow of balls what I wanted is to generate balls rapidly as the speed increases. So there should be a direct relationship between spawning interval and speed of the stream.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple application of the distance-velocity-time triangle:

[image: Diagram showing relationships between distance, speed, and time.]

(Image via [BBC "Bitesize Maths"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/standard/maths_i/numbers/dst/revision/1/))

```
float timeBetweenSpawns = spaceBetweenBalls/ballSpeed;
```

This relies on your units being consistent between the three variables. So if `timeBetweenSpawns` is measured in seconds then the `spaceBetweenBalls` should be measured in world units and the `ballSpeed` measured in world units per second.